# Web usage monitoring with Python

Tags: java, python, logging, sniffer

I want to write a script to store and analyze my Internet usage, but beside a simple list of pages visited, I want to include a "coming from" and "going to" for every page, so I can display the data as a weighted directed graph. But I don't know what to use.

*Since its my first attempt at using the internet from outside of a browser, I have no clue what keywords to look for. Most of the things I bumped into are very complex and only useful for network admins, but I don't care for all that low level data, all i need is the URL. Besides, monitoring only the transmitted data wouldn't tell me what I did in order for it to be transmitted (I guess).*

This problem sounds like a job for a Firefox Plugin, but apparently they aren't allowed to write data to disk, and I would rather avoid touching JavaScript for just one project.

Ideally it should handle clickable links as well as bookmarks and manual address entries, and also multiple tabs or windows. Let me just give you an example:

- open Firefox, startpage is google.com
- open Stackexchange in another tab
- go to stackoverflow, search and browse through questions
- change to google tab, search for lolcats, click on first result (icanhas.cheezburger.com) and read a few pages
- go to facebook
- go to google, close firefox

This should produce the following result:

- add_node('google')
- add_node('stackexchange')
- add_node('stackoverflow'); add_edge('stackexchange', 'stackoverlow')
- add_node('cheezburger'); add_edge('google', 'cheezburger')
- add_node('facebook'); add_edge('cheezeburger', 'facebook')
- add_edge('facebook', 'google')

or at least list the pages in the order they were loaded, then i can add a node for each unique entry and iterate through pairs to add the edges, but this result would be wrong if i used multiple tabs

**Summary:**
Using Python or Java I want to monitor my internet traffic (at least) or Webbrowser (preferably?) such that whenever a link is clicked, an address is entered manually or a bookmark is loaded, the target location but also the origin (URL of currently active tab) is returned. If this is possible, nudge me in the right direction.

Comment: couldnt you just use a daemon and monitor the history file (http://computer-forensics.sans.org/blog/2010/01/21/google-chrome-forensics)

Comment: have you thought of using a proxy which logs into a file?

Comment: the chrome history file carries almost all the information i need, except for the origin of the URL request, so if i open multiple google results in new tabs they will be linked to each other instead all of them being linked to google.